# Create a folder in a directory and copy files from another file into the new folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a new database for where I work. It is creating quotes for jobs. When I click the save button its save the quote and opens a new folder which gets its name from three fields on the form. I want it to import or copy files from another folder in the directory to the newly created folder.

I have tried to use the copyfolder function and it does copy the files but to the main folder where all the quotes are held and not into the newly created folder.

```
    On Error GoTo btnOK_Click_Error

    Const strParent = "C:\Users\r.jones\Desktop\Quotes\ "
    Dim Strquotenumber As String
    Dim Strsite As String
    Dim StrprojDesc As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim Strspace As String

    Strspace = Space(1) & "- "

    Strquotenumber = Me.QuoteNumber
    Strsite = Me.Txtsite
    StrprojDesc = Me.Project_Description

    strFolder = strParent & Strquotenumber & Strspace & Strsite & Strspace & StrprojDesc
    If Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder


    Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus

    If Me.Dirty Then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frmquotebook"

btnOK_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

btnOK_Click_Error:
    MsgBox "Error" & " In Attempting To Create New Folder. All Fields Must Be Filled In." & vbCrLf_
    Cancel = True
    Resume btnOK_Click_Exit
```

Is it possible to do this as I have not been able to find anything on it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some file system routines I use, wrapping the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` Object:

```
Public Function FileExists(FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = fso.FileExists(FileName)
End Function

Public Sub DeleteFile(FileName As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FileExists(FileName) Then fso.DeleteFile FileName, True
End Sub

Public Sub CopyFile(Source As String, Destination As String, Optional force As Boolean = False)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FileExists(Source) Then
        fso.CopyFile Source, Destination, force
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CreateFolder(Folder As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim TempFolder As String
    Dim Folders As Object
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Position = 0
    TempFolder = ""
    strArr = Split(Folder, "\")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
        If Not fso.FolderExists(TempFolder & strArr(i) & "\") Then
            Set Folders = fso.GetFolder(TempFolder).subFolders
            Folders.Add (strArr(i))
        End If
        TempFolder = TempFolder & strArr(i) & "\"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am new to Access. Does this go on the form code or would it be created as a module and then called.

Comment: Any where you want, better put in a spacial module, for more efficient code reuse.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this code is meant to do. I need to create a new folder and move files from one folder to another but this code dosen't appear to have any of those components in it unless I am not seeing it.

Comment: `CreateFolder` creates an new folder, or an entire path of folders, and `CopyFile` copies a file to an existing folder.

Comment: So how would i go about calling these when I click a button. I see what you mean now and I just need to know 1 where to put these and 2 how to call them. Thanks

Comment: Put these subs in a new module, and name it _ModFuleSystem_. Next, replace line `If Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strFolder` with `CreateFolder strFolder`. After that you copy the file from source location to it's new destination, using `CopyFile`. I don't see in the code witch file you want to copy, you will just have to fill in the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over each file in the source directory and cop it over to the destination directory

```
Sub CopyFilesInDirectoryToFolder(SourceDirectory As String, DestinationDirectory As String)
    Dim fileName As String
    If Not Right(SourceDirectory, 1) = Application.PathSeparator Then SourceDirectory = SourceDirectory & Application.PathSeparator
    If Not Right(DestinationDirectory, 1) = Application.PathSeparator Then DestinationDirectory = DestinationDirectory & Application.PathSeparator
    fileName = Dir(SourceDirectory)
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        CopyFile SourceDirectory & fileName, DestinationDirectory & fileName
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```